# Concatenate single column from multiple rows into single column seperated by ',' in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

I have the table EMP, in RDBMS oracle 10g and i would like get the output as follows

```
EMPNO   ENAME      Concat_column

7369    SMITH      SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES,MARTIN,BLAKE,CLARK,SCOTT,KING,TURNER,ADAMS,JAMES,FORD,MILLER
7499    ALLEN
7521    WARD
7566    JONES
7654    MARTIN
7698    BLAKE
7782    CLARK
7788    SCOTT
7839    KING
7844    TURNER
7876    ADAMS
7900    JAMES
7902    FORD
7934    MILLER
```

Please help me.

Thank you in advance and Sorry for my English and typing mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query, maybe will be useful:

```
SELECT rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, y.NAME || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') Concat_column
FROM EMP y
```

You can try this here (**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84232/1)**).

**Second version, maybe this is exactly what you want**:

```
SELECT a.EMPNO, a.NAME, b.Concat_column
FROM EMP a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    7369 AS EMPNO, 
    'SMITH' AS NAME,
    rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, y.NAME || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') AS Concat_column
  FROM EMP y 
) b ON a.EMPNO = b.EMPNO
```

Link to **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84232/5)**.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Hall has a page that lists a variety of [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

I personally prefer the user-defined aggregate function but there are a number of other techniques that work as well.